# How to modify data in array before sending to view?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, controller

I currently send some data as an array from my CodeIgniter controller to a view:

```
//Send data to template
$this->load->view('generator/content', $data);
```

Where `$data` is:

```
$data = array_merge($page, $posts);
```

I wish to modify some of the data in `$posts` before sending it to the view, by calling a function/method inside my library:

```
if (!empty($posts)) {   
    $posts = $this->my_library->modifyPosts($posts, $page_ID);
}
```

The stuff inside the function/method includes `str_replace`, exploding strings, time formatting and generally turning the data from the array into a usable format. From what I understand, it's best to do this stuff using a library.

Is there a way I can rebuild and return the array to the controller from the library, so that when I pass the data to the view it is ready to be presented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should be calling the library function from the controller anyway. So in the controller you might have

`$posts = $this->my_library->modify_something($posts);`

and then your library can do it's thing and return `$posts` in the new "usable format"

Then it's just fine from there, add the data to the `$data` array and pass it to your view.

Comment: Well the `$posts` in its original form comes from the Facebook PHP SDK. The extra functions come from another library I have set up with my own functions. Both libraries have been called from the controller.

Comment: @Joe - well, you can still pull in $posts from the facebook library and then pass it to your library right?

Comment: Yeah, I can pass the $posts to the other library OK, I just can't think of a way to get it back to the controller in a nice way. Simply performing my cleanup functions and returning the results doesn't have the desired effect. Ho hum.

Comment: @Joe - So just to be clear. From your controller, call the facebook library like so: `$posts = $this->facebook_lib->function_name();`. Then call your custom library like so (from the controller still): `$posts = $this->custom_lib->function_name($posts);`. What isn't working when you do this? You have access to the $posts var the entire time, and your controller can send it to the view when you're done with it.